# Detecting Fake Port / Service in Bash Script | portspoof

Tags: linux, bash, sockets, tcp, netcat

Can we detect if the open port is either fake or not? Because I've scanned a target website with a range of port from 1-3500, hoping to get at least HTTP and MySQL. Instead, I got all of 3500 are open ports, with services that are not common with my usage. I'm using Netcat to perform the scan in a for loop:

```sh
for port in $(seq $min $max); do
    netcat -zvv "$host" $port 2>&1 | grep "succeeded" & wait
done
```

```
Connection to xyz.com 1 port [tcp/tcpmux] succeeded!
Connection to xyz.com 2 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
Connection to xyz.com 3 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
Connection to xyz.com 4 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
Connection to xyz.com 5 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
Connection to xyz.com 6 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
Connection to xyz.com 7 port [tcp/echo] succeeded!
Connection to xyz.com 8 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
Connection to xyz.com 9 port [tcp/discard] succeeded!
Connection to xyz.com 10 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
Connection to xyz.com 11 port [tcp/systat] succeed!
...
Connection to xyz.com 3500 port [tcp/*] succeed!
```

Is this even normal?

Comment: Reference for the projects on emulates tcp port: https://github.com/drk1wi/portspoof. Really cool stuff btw

Comment: Disclaimer, the website are purposely to be pen-tested. I am doing a sweep port scan. The results are also the same by using Nmap

Comment: Cute toy. You could probably try to test its "fakeness" by probing further, e.g. inducing an error, checking responses for consistency, etc. Focusing on the protocols you're interested in could allow you to focus your probes on more likely candidates (though keep in mind, someone could always produce a better fake).

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/180109

Comment: Yeah I think it need to go deeper than checking if the ports are open or not. Didn't even know there's a downside of using it in a backend, according to your thread. Thanks man, I'll catch up if there's any progress ahead.